# Pagination in Codeigniter not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

My Model

```
 public function catproduct($limit , $offset, $Catvalue){



    $query = $this->db
                      ->select('*')
                      ->from('products')
                      ->where('product_cats' , $Catvalue)
                      ->limit($limit , $offset)
                      ->get();

    return $query->result_array();

}
```

My controller

```
$config = [
        'base_url'   =>  base_url('product?catVal='.$this->input->get('catVal', true)),
        'per_page'   =>  3,
        'total_rows' =>  $this->slider_model->num_rows($this->input->get('catVal', true)),

     ];


     $this->pagination->initialize($config);


    $product['cat_products'] = $this->slider_model->catproduct($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3), $this->input->get('catVal', true));

    $product['sidegetsub'] = $this->slider_model->getsub();
    $this->load->view('product', $product);
```

Pagination Showing me on Url http://mywebsite/product?catVal=8
Like this : 1 2 3 > Last ›
but its not working when i press when i press 2 or 3 its not working 
Url link gets change after click 
Url : http://mywebsite/product?catVal=8/12

Please how can i make it work any Answer ?

Comment: use $config[‘page_query_string’] = TRUE; while initializing pagination

Comment: try passing only the base url on `base_url` param. Eg.: http://mywebsite/index.php/controller/method